Manual Failover of SQL Server Distributed Availability Group
Is anyone able to kindly shed some light on an issue for me please? I have two Distributed Availability Group environments, one is SQL 2019 and the other is SQL 2022. The SQL 2019 environment is fine, and I can manually failover the DAG and failback. However, the SQL 2022 seems to be giving a different behaviour.
Following the steps at [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=automatic
SQL 2022 has an extra step:
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP distributedag
SET (REQUIRED_SYNCHRONIZED_SECONDARIES_TO_COMMIT = 1);
which I did.
However, at Step 5 - Testing the failover readiness, the query given does not produce the same last_hardened_lsn for both availability groups of the DAG per database. The DR site seems to always be behind.
I've also tried doing it the SQL 2019 way i.e. without setting REQUIRED_SYNCHRONIZED_SECONDARIES_TO_COMMIT = 1 and even that doesn't seem to work. The DR is still behind.
I'd appreciate some thoughts on this please.
Thank you. Please note, I am new to DAGs, just learning them.
